# Can't create C header file to be accessible from my programs

Tags: c, header

I made up my project, saved main and c source in one file, and saved the header file in the include directory of codeblocks.
When I call my functions from within the project main function, it compiles beautifully.. but when I `#include` the header to other files for use, the compiler cannot find the functions. The prototypes are in the header, but their definition is in the source code which is in another file. I can access preprocessor constants and macros stored in the header, but the link between the function prototypes and their source code seems not to exist outside the actual project.

My goal was to make header files just like the existing ones I was using (stdio.h, stdlib.h, etc.). I can't find anything helpful on that anywhere. Help me, I've been at this for days!

I know I can make .c files with functions which is way easier, but I want the challenge, want to create lib files, and I'm a performance freak (as far as I know using .h files instead of .c files is much more efficient, can't remember why, though.)

header file:

```
        #ifndef FIRO_H_INCLUDED
        #define FIRO_H_INCLUDED

        #include <stdbool.h>

        #define MA_TA 69

        bool checkprime(unsigned long long);
        int square(int);

        #endif // FIRO_H_INCLUDED
```

source code:

```
        #include "firo.h"
        #include <math.h>

        bool checkprime(unsigned long long prime)
        {
            unsigned long long root=(unsigned long long)(sqrt(prime)+1);
            unsigned long long i;
            for(i=2; i<=root; i<3?(i++):(i+=2))
            {
                if(prime%i==0)
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        int square(int a)
        {
            return a*a;
        }
```

I was hoping for an answer, not irony. I did read somewhere that segmenting code into .h files and source codes separately would somehow dinamically speed up the process of accesing functions, don't blame me for not knowing how that works. The checkprime function I actualy use, the rest is just for testing.

Comment: The word you're looking for is `linkage`.

Comment: Can we please see the header?

Comment: And .h is not more efficient then a shared library in larger cases, just in smaller ones. Especially for things like the C library. I shudder at the thought of a system that has the C library as static...

Comment: Did you create a project and add all the source files to it? Otherwise, code::blocks cannot know what files it should link together.

Comment: Please show us the compiler error(s).

Comment: "I'm a performance freak" - you better not be one until you actually know stuff about performance. "using .h files instead of .c files is much more efficient" - This doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Shahbaz: What Code::Blocks thinks isn't that important. This has more to do with the compiler.

Comment: Yes Shahbaz, I created a new project, and added 2 files to it, first the header then another defining the functions. Compiled, worked great.

Comment: I don't know Code::Blocks, but in the straight compiler way you would need to specify either an object or a library when linking the final program.  (The standard library is usually linked by default.)

Comment: That loop is very inefficient.  The speed of calling a function is not your primary concern.

Comment: paddy, are you thinking of adding an array to store primes up to the argument(starting with a few basic values such as 2, 3, 7) and checking the number only against found primes? I know I can do that. I wanted a function to establish if a nr is prime, not find all primes up to that given nr. This is a mere example, I don't want to do this just for the sake of the checkprime function.

Comment: @kundrata, so my comment was your answer?

Comment: @Shahbaz, well you asked me a question, I answered you, now I'm hoping you can give me that answer. Yes it's about the compiler.

Comment: @kundrata, you said "Compiled, worked great." So what's the problem now?

Comment: Well, I explained that it always compiled while in the project, while linking them before running. It's when I call the header from another, independent file that I can't use the functions in it, they're somehow not linked to they're definitions in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeblocks, you'll have to create a different project for the static lib and build it. Then, you may open your main project's linker settings (Project -> Build Options -> Linker settings tab) and add your library to the "Link libraries" list.

Comment: But I have to agree with the other commenters. Don't try to optimize what you don't fully understand yet. Once your program is finished, profile it, find its bottlenecks and fix them. You'll be surprised how actual bottlenecks differ from ones you expect to see.